# Redirección .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

intento redireccionar cualquier subdominio terminado en /ingreso al dominio principal, terminado en /ingreso

Me explico:

Necesito que todo usuario que ingrese a

https://cualquiersubdominio.misitioweb.com/ingreso

sea dirigido a

https://misitioweb.com/ingreso

Lo estoy intentando así pero no funciona como debería

```html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.misitioweb\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /ingreso$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://misitioweb.com/ingreso [R=302,L]
```

(*actualizado) Veo que el asunto está en esta línea, ya que si la comento cuando entro a cualquier subdominio la redirección se ejecuta bien

```html
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /ingreso$
```

¿Alguna idea de qué estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias.

Comment: ¿No debería ser una redirección 301, en lugar de la 302 que estás usando? Lo digo porque la redirección 302 es temporal, mientras que la 301 es permanente

Comment: Gracias, buen punto. Pero aún así sigue sin funcionar. No veo que sea tan complicado, pero no entiendo por qué no funciona. ¿Más ideas? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo he conseguido.
Comparto las reglas finales.

```html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.misitioweb\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/ingreso
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://misitioweb.com/ingreso [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrías intentar lo siguiente, adaptándolo para tu caso.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http://www.newdomain.com/page.html" [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.newdomain.org/page.html
```

Comment: Gracias. Ya he publicado las reglas que funcionaron.